# Change date settings in the Sharepoint Online Admin Centre to DDMMYY

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time, regional-settings, sharepoint-admin-center

I'd like to change the date format settings for the Sharepoint Admin Centre.  Currently the date is displayed using US MMDDYY (which for me is illogical), to the settings used by most of the world, DDMMYY.

Screen shot from Sharepoint Online Admin Centre:

[image: US date format settings]

I've [read on SP Technet](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/60) that this date setting can't be changed, which surely can't be true...

I also use the 'export' feature to get a summary of the SP Admin Centre in Excel, for analysis purposes, the file then needs formatting to try to make better sense of the dates.

### Other Notes

One thing I've found is that on the User Profiles menu it allows me to change language/region/date format settings (see pic below).  However, I'm not sure that the Sharepoint Admin Centre settings can be changed via these settings.  I'm Sharepoint Admin, so I think this menu gives me the power to change my user profile preferences and then to apply the same settings to my colleagues i.e. 'For Me' or 'Everyone'.  We're UK-based, so would all use the same settings.

The url of the User Profile menu is: https://MyDomain.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/tenantprofileadmin/ProfAdminEdit.aspx?guid=459abf6c-c935-4340-af87-102194f7f02c&q=tall&ConsoleView=Active&ProfileType=User&ApplicationID=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

[image: user profile local settings]

Thanks for any advice on this, even if it's just to confirm that this setting is 'set in stone' and simply cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my research, we could not change date formatting in the SharePoint Admin Center, it is by design.

I would suggest you submit a feedback via **[User Voice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/)**.

Here is a similar case for reference：

- **[Changing date format in lists of active sites in Sharepoint admin
  centre](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/changing-date-format-in-lists-of-active-sites-in-sharepoint/m-p/2077028)**

Comment: Wow, seems pretty crazy that they don't allow this setting to be changed!  Thanks for taking the time to answer and posting the links.

Comment: I've logged feedback via User Voice - please see here and feel free to upvote if it's something you'd find useful: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/43580571-sharepoint-admin-centre-in-ddmmyy-format

Comment: Wow, thanks Microsoft - my post on sharepoint.uservoice has been deleted with no response from them.  Good work Microsoft!

Comment: I've since found that accessing the personal account settings manages the date format: https://myaccount.microsoft.com/settingsandprivacy/language

Answer (score 0):

I have just changed the regional settings for the SharePoint Admin Centre on my test tenant.

Just append /_layouts/15/regionalsetng.aspx to your Admin Centre Url then you'll be able to access the regional settings page. E.g.

https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/regionalsetng.aspx

Although I'm not sure if the settings will be reset by some Microsoft process, or if changing the settings will have any side effect.

Comment: Thanks for posting, I'll need to pass that on to a colleague who administers our system.  I'll see what happens.